# Good (free or paid) command line based Antivirus for Linux

Tags: linux, security, command-line, antivirus

I am using [ClamAV](https://www.clamav.net/) for some time now and it is quite okay. But I would like to give some other Antivirus Softwares/tools a try.

I am looking for something that:

1. is Command-line based i.e. GUI is optional
2. can run in a Docker container
3. detects latest viruses

Even a paid solution would be good enough.